# Append output of R CMD BATCH

Tags: r, batch-file

i have a for loop in a batch  file which runs the same r script with different parameters and i want all output to be appended to the same file.

here is an example:

**Batch Code**

```
for %%i in ([folder name]) do (
  R CMD BATCH --slave "--args %%i" Script.R output.out
)
```

**Script.R Code**

```
cmdArgs = commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
cat("Args: ", cmdArgs[1], "\n")
cat("End")
```

I have tried using 2>&1 and it's not working.

I am using a windows machine and prefer not to redirect output from within the R script and can't user RScript, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply enclose all the output lines in the batch with additional parentheses and redirect that to a file:

```
(
for %%i in ([folder name]) do R CMD BATCH --slave "--args %%i" Script.R output.out
) >Output.txt
```

This `[folder name]` is only pseudo code and won't work.